# Bilingual language settings?

Tags: languages

I would like my phone to recognize English and French words.

Also I'd like the swype typing to work this way.

What is the simplest way to accomplish this?

I have a moto G, android 5.1

Comment: I honestly don't know.  I'm thinking about things like gmail, SMS, Google Maps, Drive, etc.

When I go into settings, I see "language &input" where I can select a single language  at the top and also select a language for the keyboard.

Comment: I'm talking about auto-correct, etc. with typing.  I actually never use VTT.

Comment: Ooooopsss. I took it all the way wrong then. Refer to Dan Hulme's answer. It should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to change the keyboard settings. Not all keyboard apps can handle multiple languages. On some, you have to install the language(s) you want from the keyboard's settings menu, and then switch the language through the menu (the one you already mentioned) or through a swipe gesture on the keyboard (such as swiping the space bar left or right).

Some keyboard apps can work out what language you're typing in on-the-fly, without you having to say explicitly. [SwiftKey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey) is an example of a keyboard that works this way: just enable all the languages you want through its settings, and it will detect what language you're typing as soon as you've written a couple of words.